# Xcode Cloud to Bitbucket server - Connection Error -"Your hostname must be publicly resolvable."

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, xcode-cloud

We are trying to implement Xcode Cloud for CI. We have a private repository in GitLab that can be accessed via VPN. We are experiencing the following errors while connecting Xcode Cloud to GitLab. We followed the steps provided by Apple.

> Connection Error to https://alm------.com. Your hostname must be publicly resolvable.

[image: Xcode Cloud error]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error message says the hostname is not publicly resolvable. Meaning if you type in the domain name in Safari's address field when you are on the open Internet (not connected to your company's VPN), Safari will report that it could not locate the server.

You mention that you are following the steps given by Apple but did not provide details. So I can only provide a general answer here. Off the top of my head, your setup must have the following:

- Your private GitLab server must not be only accessible via VPN. Xcode
  Cloud/Apple will not have VPN access to your company private network.
- The domain name you use must be resolvable on the Internet. Meaning
  that there is a publicly accessible DNS that can turn your domain
  name to a publicly routable IP Address. *Non-publicly routable IP
  Address look something like `192.168.x.x`, `10.x.x.x`,
  `172.(16-31).x.x`.*
- Your company network's firewall must allow traffic coming from Apple to
  access the server where your GitLab instance is on.